# eventmachine gem error OpenSSL on El Capitan

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, eventmachine

I am attempting to write a simple ruby app with websockets using the Faye-Websocket gem and the EventMachine gem.

I'm working on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

I installed OpenSSL using homebrew 
`/usr/local/Cellar/openssl`

and successfully installed eventmachine into my local gems:

```
$ KG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/pkgconfig" sudo gem install  eventmachine

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.2.0.1
1 gem installed
```

I run a successful bundle install into my application:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using addressable 2.4.0
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.2
Using eventmachine 1.2.0.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using http-form_data 1.0.1
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using unf 0.1.4
Installing websocket-driver 0.6.4 with native extensions
Using domain_name 
Installing faye-websocket 0.10.4
Using http-cookie 1.0.2
Using http 2.0.1
Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 14 gems now installed.
```

However I am still receiving the following error when attempting to run my application:

```
$ bundle exec ruby shield.rb
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Encryption not available on this event-machine
Abort trap: 6
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?